# ¿Cómo usar la función DatePicker de JQuery para desplegar un calendario al dar click en un icono?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-datepicker

Estoy Empezando a trabajar con la función `DatePicker` de `JQuery-UI`, entonces he visto algunos tutoriales y son como el siguiente codigo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>DatePicker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fa-regular.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fa-solid.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fa-brands.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fontawesome.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="height:130px;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker10'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    Calendario
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker10').datetimepicker({
                viewMode: 'years',
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Al dar click en la palabra calendario (Donde después lo cambiare por un icono) tiene que desplegar el calendario para agregarlo en el input.

El **problema es** que al dar click nada sucede.

Me estoy basando en los ejemplos de [Aquí](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

Comment: Lo que percibo de tu código es que te falta importar las librerías de datetimepicker en proyecto. te dejo el siguiente link para que lo cheques https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/

Comment: ¿Como seria eso? Estoy chechando el ejemplo  de https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ y no tiene nada mas que eso.

Comment: Tu pregunta es acerca de jquery-ui pero el ejemplo del  link es de bootstrap.js lo que no es lo mismo.

Comment: Soy nuevo en esto, me puse a buscar y me base de alli, pero, ya encontre la respuesta que necesitaba, haciendo pruebas y buscando en internet llegue a la solucion

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#fecha").datepicker({
   changeMonth:true,
   changeYear: true
  });
  $('#icono').click(function() {
    $("#fecha").focus();
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>DatePicker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

</head>
<body>
  <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">Fecha:</label>
      <input type="text" id="fecha" name="fecha" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="fa fa-calendar" id="icono"></i>
    </div>
  </form>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/date_local.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Esta es la solucion que encontre a mi problema, la obtuve [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43605222/jquery-datepicker-on-click-of-icon)